Power automate Desktop: Launch SAP Action Error
Iam using the latest power automate desktop app sap logon 750. While using Lauch SAP Action or Attach action, it opens the the SAP Logon App. But it throws the following error later:
Correlation Id: 88bf9d52-1798-4a98-9a61-c755c064ce36
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {62341062-29BC-4DCE-A87A-DC0CB19BF230} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.Desktop.Actions.SDK.ActionException:
Does Anyone know the actual reason behind it?
I have tried using SSO and Manual Login as well. It didnt work. I checked the server description and other details as well. Iam pretty sure the details are proper.
